# Weird *ngFor issue

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a book modal, which has a name and enable flag. If the book is enabled I need to show a buy button in the view.

Sample code:

```
Books.ts

export class Book{
Name:string;
IsEnable:boolean;
}

books.component.ts

...
books = [{"Name":"A", "IsEnable":"True"},{"Name":"B", "IsEnable":"False"}];
....
getEligibleBooks(book){
console.log(book);
return book.IsEnable;
}

books.component.html

<div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <button *ngIf="getEligibleBooks(book)"
    class="link-button" style="display: inline-block"
    (click)="addEvent(true)"><i class="add-circled"></i>
       Buy
    </button>
</div>
```

Issue:
I have only two books but when I run the code, I'm getting multiple logs in the console. The above code is just a sample. The real code has api calls inside that getEligible method. And for two books, that method is calling endlessly. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Based on your code I think the problem is where you call you're getEligible method?

Comment: Without calling that how can I check and display the button?

Comment: I'm sorry I mean in which place you call it for example in ngOnInit

Comment: No, I call it in the html *ngIf -- `*ngIf="getEligibleBooks(book)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, you are getting these logs whenever a change detection cycle runs in your angular app to see if those two books changed, if yes then update the view. Change detection cycle events can happen on may cases most common of which are browser events like, click, scroll, ajax requests, timer events etc. This is the reason why we should write as less code as possible in property getters.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan As said in the answer, this is normal. You don't want your view to be updated when the contents of `books` change? This is how Angular keeps track of the code it is displaying in the view

Comment: @RanjithVaradan your function only returns a boolean at the time. Just remove your function and directly return the boolean. For more complex function, you can use the `onPush` change detection strategy.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan You can change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` or even detach change detection and run it manually

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Right, for more complex logic and depending on when you want to update the view, please read `onPush` change detection strategy.

Comment: Ok. I'll try adding changedetectionstrategy. and let you know :)

Comment: Added ChangeDetectiongStrategy to onpush, which resolves this multiple call but some of the other components are not working :( which means I can't use this.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan You can use this, first segregate your requirements, making change detection to OnPush will only check for props if their references change or you call change detection manually. Just changing the change detection strategy will lead to more problems than it will solve.

Comment: need help on this. another idea -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374349/how-to-use-map-and-assign-the-value-back. but no idea how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens since the change detection loop calls your function several times. Why not use

```html
<button *ngIf="book.isEnable" ... >
```

Or you need to do something additional actions when your books are being displayed?

[Read more about change detection in angular](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)

Comment: As I said before, the code used here is just a sample code, the real code has api calls and complex logics.